# how to group a date column based on date range in oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a table which contains a feedback about a product.It has feedback type (positive ,negative) which is a text column, date on which comments made. I need to get total count of positive ,negative feedback for particular time period . For example if the date range is 30 days, I need to get total count of positive ,negative feedback for 4 weeks , if the date range is 6  months , I need to get total count of positive ,negative feedback for each month. How to group the count based on date.

```
+------+------+----------+----------+---------------+--+--+--+
| Slno | User | Comments |   type   | commenteddate |  |  |  |
+------+------+----------+----------+---------------+--+--+--+
|    1 | a    | aaaa     | positive | 22-jun-2016   |  |  |  |
|    2 | b    | bbb      | positive | 1-jun-2016    |  |  |  |
|    3 | c    | qqq      | negative | 2-jun-2016    |  |  |  |
|    4 | d    | ccc      | neutral  | 3-may-2016    |  |  |  |
|    5 | e    | www      | positive | 2-apr-2016    |  |  |  |
|    6 | f    | s        | negative | 11-nov-2015   |  |  |  |
+------+------+----------+----------+---------------+--+--+--+
```

Query i tried is

SELECT type, to_char(commenteddate,'DD-MM-YYYY'), Count(type) FROM comments GROUP BY type, to_char(commenteddate,'DD-MM-YYYY');

Comment: Please show table schema, sample data, and expected output, and what you have tried.  Thanks.

Comment: I have added a sample table and query. I need to group the type based on date intervals. For example if the date interval is 30 days, I need to get total count of positive ,negative feedback for 4 weeks , if the date range is 6 months , I need to get total count of positive ,negative feedback for each month. How to group the count based on date. i am trying this query in a stored procedure. Input is date interval

Comment: Please also show EXPECTED OUTPUT from this sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a kick at the can...

Assumptions:

- you want to be able to switch the groupings to weekly or monthly only
- the start of the first period will be the first date in the feedback data; intervals will be calculated from this initial date
- output will show feedback value, time period, count
- time periods will not overlap so periods will be x -> x + interval - 1 day
- time of day is not important (time for commented dates is always 00:00:00)

First, create some sample data (100 rows):

```
drop table product_feedback purge;

create table product_feedback
as
select rownum as slno
, chr(65 + MOD(rownum, 26)) as userid
, lpad(chr(65 + MOD(rownum, 26)), 5, chr(65 + MOD(rownum, 26))) as comments
, trunc(sysdate) + rownum + trunc(dbms_random.value * 10) as commented_date
, case mod(rownum * TRUNC(dbms_random.value * 10), 3) 
       when 0 then 'positive' 
       when 1 then 'negative' 
       when 2 then 'neutral' end as feedback
from dual
connect by level <= 100
;
```

Here's what my sample data looks like:

```
select *
from product_feedback
;

SLNO    USERID  COMMENTS    COMMENTED_DATE  FEEDBACK
1   B   BBBBB   2016-08-06  neutral
2   C   CCCCC   2016-08-06  negative
3   D   DDDDD   2016-08-14  positive
4   E   EEEEE   2016-08-16  negative
5   F   FFFFF   2016-08-09  negative
6   G   GGGGG   2016-08-14  positive
7   H   HHHHH   2016-08-17  positive
8   I   IIIII   2016-08-18  positive
9   J   JJJJJ   2016-08-12  positive
10  K   KKKKK   2016-08-15  neutral
11  L   LLLLL   2016-08-23  neutral
12  M   MMMMM   2016-08-19  positive
13  N   NNNNN   2016-08-16  neutral
...
```

Now for the fun part. Here's the gist:

- find out what the earliest and latest commented dates are in the data
- include a query where you can set the time period (to "WEEKS" or "MONTHS")
- generate all of the (weekly or monthly) time periods between the min/max dates
- join the product feedback to the time periods (commented date between start and end) with an outer join in case you want to see all time periods whether or not there was any feedback
- group the joined result by feedback, period start, and period end, and set up a column to count one of the 3 possible feedback values

x

```
with 
min_max_dates -- get earliest and latest feedback dates
as
(select min(commented_date) min_date, max(commented_date) max_date
from product_feedback
)
, time_period_interval
as
(select 'MONTHS' as tp_interval -- set the interval/time period here
   from dual
)
, -- generate all time periods between the start date and end date
time_periods (start_of_period, end_of_period, max_date, time_period) -- recursive with clause - fun stuff!
as
(select mmd.min_date as start_of_period
      , CASE WHEN tpi.tp_interval = 'WEEKS' 
             THEN mmd.min_date + 7
             WHEN tpi.tp_interval = 'MONTHS' 
             THEN ADD_MONTHS(mmd.min_date, 1)
             ELSE NULL
        END - 1 as end_of_period
, mmd.max_date
, tpi.tp_interval as time_period
   from time_period_interval tpi
        cross join
        min_max_dates mmd
UNION ALL
select CASE WHEN time_period = 'WEEKS' 
             THEN start_of_period + 7 * (ROWNUM )
             WHEN time_period = 'MONTHS' 
             THEN ADD_MONTHS(start_of_period, ROWNUM)
             ELSE NULL
        END as start_of_period
, CASE WHEN time_period = 'WEEKS' 
             THEN start_of_period + 7 * (ROWNUM + 1)
             WHEN time_period = 'MONTHS' 
             THEN ADD_MONTHS(start_of_period, ROWNUM + 1)
             ELSE NULL
        END - 1 as end_of_period
, max_date
, time_period
from time_periods
where end_of_period <= max_date 
)
-- now put it all together
select pf.feedback
     , tp.start_of_period
     , tp.end_of_period
     , count(*) as feedback_count
from time_periods tp
left outer join
product_feedback pf
on pf.commented_date between tp.start_of_period and tp.end_of_period
group by tp.start_of_period
       , tp.end_of_period
       , pf.feedback
order by pf.feedback
       , tp.start_of_period
;
```

Output:

```
negative    2016-08-06  2016-09-05  6
negative    2016-09-06  2016-10-05  7
negative    2016-10-06  2016-11-05  8
negative    2016-11-06  2016-12-05  1
neutral     2016-08-06  2016-09-05  6
neutral     2016-09-06  2016-10-05  5
neutral     2016-10-06  2016-11-05  11
neutral     2016-11-06  2016-12-05  2
positive    2016-08-06  2016-09-05  17
positive    2016-09-06  2016-10-05  16
positive    2016-10-06  2016-11-05  15
positive    2016-11-06  2016-12-05  6
```

-- EDIT --

New and improved, all in one easy to use procedure. (I will assume you can configure the procedure to make use of the query in whatever way you need.) I made some changes to simplify the CASE statements in a few places and note that for whatever reason using a LEFT OUTER JOIN in the main SELECT results in an ORA-600 error for me so I switched it to INNER JOIN.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE feedback_counts(p_days_chosen IN NUMBER, p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN

OPEN p_cursor FOR
    with 
    min_max_dates -- get earliest and latest feedback dates
    as
    (select min(commented_date) min_date, max(commented_date) max_date
    from product_feedback
    )
    , time_period_interval
    as
    (select CASE 
             WHEN p_days_chosen BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 'DAYS'
             WHEN p_days_chosen > 10 AND p_days_chosen <=31 THEN 'WEEKS'
             WHEN p_days_chosen > 31 AND p_days_chosen <= 365 THEN 'MONTHS'
             ELSE '3-MONTHS'
        END as tp_interval -- set the interval/time period here
        from dual --(SELECT p_days_chosen as days_chosen from dual)
    )    
    , -- generate all time periods between the start date and end date
    time_periods (start_of_period, end_of_period, max_date, tp_interval) -- recursive with clause - fun stuff!
    as
    (select mmd.min_date as start_of_period
          , CASE tpi.tp_interval 
                 WHEN 'DAYS'
                 THEN mmd.min_date + 1
                 WHEN 'WEEKS' 
                 THEN mmd.min_date + 7
                 WHEN 'MONTHS' 
                 THEN mmd.min_date + 30
                 WHEN '3-MONTHS'
                 THEN mmd.min_date + 90
                 ELSE NULL
            END - 1 as end_of_period
    , mmd.max_date
    , tpi.tp_interval
       from time_period_interval tpi
            cross join
            min_max_dates mmd
    UNION ALL
    select CASE tp_interval
                 WHEN 'DAYS'
                 THEN start_of_period + 1 * ROWNUM
                 WHEN 'WEEKS' 
                 THEN start_of_period + 7 * ROWNUM 
                 WHEN 'MONTHS' 
                 THEN start_of_period + 30 * ROWNUM
                 WHEN '3-MONTHS'
                 THEN start_of_period + 90 * ROWNUM
                 ELSE NULL
            END as start_of_period
        , start_of_period
          + CASE tp_interval 
                 WHEN 'DAYS'
                 THEN 1
                 WHEN 'WEEKS' 
                 THEN 7
                 WHEN 'MONTHS' 
                 THEN 30
                 WHEN '3-MONTHS'
                 THEN 90
                 ELSE NULL
            END * (ROWNUM + 1) 
            - 1 as end_of_period
    , max_date
    , tp_interval
    from time_periods
    where end_of_period <= max_date 
    )
    -- now put it all together
    select pf.feedback
         , tp.start_of_period
         , tp.end_of_period
         , count(*) as feedback_count
    from time_periods tp
    inner join -- currently a bug that prevents the procedure from compiling with a LEFT OUTER JOIN
    product_feedback pf
    on pf.commented_date between tp.start_of_period and tp.end_of_period
    group by tp.start_of_period
           , tp.end_of_period
           , pf.feedback
    order by tp.start_of_period
           , pf.feedback
    ;
END;
```

Test the procedure (in something like SQLPlus or SQL Developer):

```
var x refcursor
exec feedback_counts(10, :x)
print :x
```

Comment: I want to group if the days chosen is less than 10, I need to get count of reviews for each day. If days chosen is greater than 10 and less than 31 days, need to group for 7 days.If the days chosen is greater than a month and less than a year, need to group for 30 days, if it is greater than a year need to group for 90 days

Comment: Days chosen how? Where? By what mechanism?

Comment: Days chosen is sent as an number to stored procedure. I need to know how I can modify the query,

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the query inside of a procedure and added more time period intervals as per your comment above.